# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required Spring JDBC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, datasource, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

i am not sure what i am doing wrong , i am trying to execute a stored-procedure using jdbc call but when ever i execute its hitting exception 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required  .

Controller Class:

```
    @Controller
    public class GpsController {

        @RequestMapping(value="h",method=RequestMethod.POST)    
        public void show(@ModelAttribute("PredefinedPath") PredefinedPath predefinedPath)

        { 

            PredefinedPathService service=new PredefinedPathService();
            //passing dto obj to service
             boolean res=   service.savePredefinedPath(predefinedPath);
        }
```

DTO CLASS:

```
    //Entity Class Getters and setters
    public class PredefinedPath {

        public int getPredefinedPath_Id() {
            return PredefinedPath_Id;
        }
        public void setPredefinedPath_Id(int predefinedPath_Id) {
            PredefinedPath_Id = predefinedPath_Id;
        }
        public String getPredefinedPath_Name() {
            return PredefinedPath_Name;
        }
        public void setPredefinedPath_Name(String predefinedPath_Name) {
            PredefinedPath_Name = predefinedPath_Name;
        }
        public String getSource() {
            return Source;
        }
        public void setSource(String source) {
            Source = source;
        }
        public String getDestination() {
            return Destination;
        }
        public void setDestination(String destination) {
            Destination = destination;
        }
        public String getEstimate_km() {
            return Estimate_km;
        }
        public void setEstimate_km(String estimate_km) {
            Estimate_km = estimate_km;
        }
        public double getSource_Latitude() {
            return Source_Latitude;
        }
        public void setSource_Latitude(double source_Latitude) {
            Source_Latitude = source_Latitude;
        }
        public double getSource_Longtitude() {
            return Source_Longtitude;
        }
        public void setSource_Longtitude(double source_Longtitude) {
            Source_Longtitude = source_Longtitude;
        }
        public double getDestination_Latitude() {
            return Destination_Latitude;
        }
        public void setDestination_Latitude(double destination_Latitude) {
            Destination_Latitude = destination_Latitude;
        }
        public double getDestination_Longtitude() {
            return Destination_Longtitude;
        }
        public void setDestination_Longtitude(double destination_Longtitude) {
            Destination_Longtitude = destination_Longtitude;
        }
        public String getEffectiveFromDate() {
            return EffectiveFromDate;
        }
        public void setEffectiveFromDate(String effectiveFromDate) {
            EffectiveFromDate = effectiveFromDate;
        }
        public String getEffectiveToDate() {
            return EffectiveToDate;
        }
        public void setEffectiveToDate(String effectiveToDate) {
            EffectiveToDate = effectiveToDate;
        }
        public int getStatus_Id() {
            return Status_Id;
        }
        public void setStatus_Id(int status_Id) {
            Status_Id = status_Id;
        }
        private int PredefinedPath_Id;
        private String PredefinedPath_Name;
        private String Source;
        private String Destination;
        private String Estimate_km;
        private double Source_Latitude;
        private double Source_Longtitude;
        private double Destination_Latitude;
        private double Destination_Longtitude;
        private String EffectiveFromDate;
        private String EffectiveToDate;
        private int Status_Id;


    }
```

DAO CLASS :

```
        import javax.sql.DataSource;

        import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource;
        import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSource;
        import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall;
        import com.Ss.App.dto.PredefinedPath;

        public class PredefinedPathDaoImpl {

             private DataSource dataSource;
               private SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall;

               public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
                  this.dataSource = dataSource;

               }


          public boolean savePredefined(PredefinedPath predefinedPathDto)
            { 


                    System.out.println("INSIDE DAO");
                    this.jdbcCall =  new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource).withProcedureName("PredefinedPath_Insert");
                    SqlParameterSource sqlParameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                    .addValue("PredefinedPath_Name", predefinedPathDto.getPredefinedPath_Name())
                    .addValue("Source", predefinedPathDto.getSource())
                    .addValue("Destination", predefinedPathDto.getDestination())
                    .addValue("Source_Latitude", predefinedPathDto.getSource_Latitude())
                    .addValue("Source_Longtitude", predefinedPathDto.getSource_Longtitude())
                    .addValue("Destination_Latitude", predefinedPathDto.getDestination_Latitude())
                    .addValue("Destination_Longtitude", predefinedPathDto.getDestination_Longtitude())
                    .addValue("EffectiveFromDate",null)
                    .addValue("EffectiveToDate",null)
                    .addValue("Status_Id", 4);
                    jdbcCall.execute(sqlParameterSource);






                return true;
            }
        }
```

Service Class:

```
    import com.Ss.App.dto.PredefinedPath;

    import com.Ss.App.model.dao.PredefinedPathDaoImpl;

    public class PredefinedPathService {

         PredefinedPathDaoImpl predefinedPathDao=new PredefinedPathDaoImpl();
         public boolean savePredefinedPath(PredefinedPath predefinedPathdto)
         {

            boolean result=predefinedPathDao.savePredefined(predefinedPathdto);

            return result;


         }
    }
```

Spring Config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.Ss.App"></context:component-scan> 

            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/view/"/>
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>

            </bean>
             <!-- Definition for studentJDBCTemplate bean -->
       <bean id="PredefinedPathDaoImpl"  class="com.Ss.App.model.dao.PredefinedPathDaoImpl">
          <property name="DataSource"  ref="dataSource" />    
       </bean>
        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName"  value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"></property>
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=test"></property>
            <property name="username" value="sa"></property>
            <property name="password" value="pass"></property>
        </bean>




    <mvc:annotation-driven />



            </beans>
```

web.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
      <display-name>SpringAngularjs</display-name>
      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>page.jsp</welcome-file>

      </welcome-file-list>
      <servlet>
      <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      </servlet>

      <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

Comment: please add the stacktrace

Comment: here is the stacktrace : http://pastebin.com/YA7KsBnA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service in your controller is not managed by Spring as you instantiate it yourself.

That's why the datasource is not set in this bean.

Replace :

```
@Controller
public class GpsController {

        @RequestMapping(value="h",method=RequestMethod.POST)    
        public void show(@ModelAttribute("PredefinedPath") PredefinedPath predefinedPath)
        { 

            PredefinedPathService service=new PredefinedPathService();
            //passing dto obj to service
             boolean res = service.savePredefinedPath(predefinedPath);
        }
}
```

By

```
@Controller
public class GpsController {
   @Autowired
   private PredefinedPathService service;

   @RequestMapping(value="h",method=RequestMethod.POST)    
   public void show(@ModelAttribute("PredefinedPath") PredefinedPath predefinedPath)
        {
            //passing dto obj to service
             boolean res = service.savePredefinedPath(predefinedPath);
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks its Fixed now .